# Lot of connections are in time wait and closed stage

Tags: go, jmeter, socketexception, gorilla

I am using gorilla/mux framework  for a rest api which inserts data into cassandra. 
When I run performance test on the api with jmeter and 2500 users , i get error of socket exception after 1500 active users . 
When i checked the connection status, lots of connections are in time wait/closed  stage while number of established connections are very low .

[image]

But when i set keepalive enabled in jmeter , there are no connections in timewait /closed stage and I get no errors

Keeping keep alive in jmeter is not my real scenario . 
How can i set keep alive through framework itself?

Comment: The framework can't force jmeter to use keepalive. If jmeter doesn't reuse connections, you are going to use a lot of ephemeral ports.

Comment: you can also reduce the time connections on JMeter host spend in TIME_WAIT state. Default times are too long on both Windows and Linux. This is the procedure for linux: lognormal.com/blog/2012/09/27/linux-tcpip-tuning

Comment: trying to modify the sysctl.conf file but getting error sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max: No such file or directory